# Worklight JSONStore result not returned

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have a function which should return the result array of a JSONStore query if it is successful. For some reason it doesn't return the result.

This is my function

```
function getJSON(){
var collectionName = 'messages';
var query = {title: 'asdf'};
var options =  {
        exact:  false,
        limit:  10
};
result = [];

WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName)
.find(query, options)
.then(function (ArrayResult) {
    result = ArrayResult;
    console.log(result);
    console.log(typeof result);
    return result;
})
.fail(function (errrorObject){
    console.log("could not get JSONStore: \n" + errrorObject);
});
```

}

and this is where it is called:

```
$("#button").click( function() {
   console.log("type of returned result in buttonClick: " + typeof getJSON());
})
```

also the console outputs appear in a weird order:

```
 "weird orderd output" CDMS_Demo.js:96
 "type of returned result in buttonClick: undefined" CDMS_Demo.html:57
 "result in getJSON: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" CDMS_Demo.js:89
 "type of result in getJSON: object" CDMS_Demo.js:90
```

Someone got an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be expecting asynchronous code to behave synchronously. Try adding a callback, some pseudocode:

```js
function getJSON (callback) {

  var collectionName = 'messages';

  var query = {title: 'asdf'};

  var options =  {
          exact:  false,
          limit:  10
  };

  WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName)

  .find(query, options)

  .then(function (arrayResult) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayResult));
      callback(arrayResult);
  })

  .fail(function (errorObject){
      console.log(errorObject.toString());
  });
}

$("#button").click(function () {

  getJSON(function (arrayResult) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayResult));
  });
});
```

Comment: JSONStore is an asynchronous API, that is why your code that uses it is asynchronous. Please click on the green checkmark next to the answer, to let other users know it's an 'accepted answer'.